# Recommended 2D barcode generator api in C

Tags: c, 2d, barcode

Can someone kindly suggest a 2D Barcode Generator library/api in C that is freely available?

Regards,
Ad

Comment: what's the output format?

Comment: @originalPoster: Google doesn't like you today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ZXing  which is avalaible in google code http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ for c++ and zint for C check the manual ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/sourceforge/z/project/zi/zint/zint/2.4.2/zint_manual_242.pdf and the source you can download it from sourceforge

Comment: Thank you Saddam.Butdoes Zxing has port to C language? I require a library which is written in C or can be ported to C

Comment: for C library you can use zint

Comment: Thank you again!. Hopefully zint library should help me. let me check the details.